# Determine the first Prolongation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups, symmetry

I am in the process of solving the equation $y''=0$ where $y=y(x)$ using symmetry methods.  I have not studied this method and am trying to teach myself by following examples I find online.

UPDATE : I have been able to determine the following based on what I read in Bluman & Anco:

UPDATE: My Attempt: (based on what I found in Bluman & Anco)

Before we move further, we need to understand the concept of the **Total Derivative Operator:**
\begin{equation}D=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\dot{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \label{eq:5} \tag{5}\end{equation}
**NB:**$DF(x,y)=F_x+y'F_y$

The **$k^{th}$** prolongation is defined by:

\begin{equation}\zeta^{(k)}(x,y)=D\zeta^{(k-1)}(x,y)-y^kD\xi \label{eq:Prol} \tag{6}\end{equation}
where $\zeta^{(0)}=\eta(x,y)$

Using the above definition we get the following:

**First Prolongation**
\begin{align} 
\zeta^{(1)} & =D\eta(x,y) -\dot{y}D(\xi(x,y)) \nonumber  \\
& = \eta_x +\dot{y}\eta_y-\dot{y} \left( \xi_x+\dot{y}\xi_y\right) \nonumber \\
& = \eta_x +\dot{y}\eta_y -\dot{y}\xi_x - \dot{y}^2\xi_y\\
 \label{eq:ProlOne} \tag{7}
\end{align}
**Second Prolongation**
\begin{align}
\zeta^{(2)} & = D\zeta^{(1)}-\ddot{y}D\xi(x,y)  \hspace{10mm} \text{$ \ddot{y}=0$  so the second term falls away} \nonumber \\
& = \eta_{xx}+\dot{y}\eta_{xy}-\dot{y}\xi_{xx}-\dot{y}^2\xi{xy}+\dot{y}\left(\eta_{xy}+\dot{y}\eta_{yy}-\dot{y}\xi_{xy}-\dot{y}^2\xi_{yy}\right) \nonumber\\
&=\eta_{xx} +\left(2\eta_{xy}-\xi_{xx}\right)\dot{y} +\left(\eta_{yy}-2\xi_{xy}\right)\dot{y}^2-\xi_{yy}\dot{y}^3\\
\label{ProlTwo} \tag{8}
\end{align}

Is this correct?

I also need to find the **Determining Equation**

Am I correct in saying the **Determining Equation** is $\zeta^{(2)}=0$ ?

If so, I need to be able to show **why** this is the case.
I am currently reading, and re-reading the sections in Bluman & Anco that apply.